# Insert Image in Excel through Matlab

Tags: excel, matlab, com, office-interop

I am using the function, `Shapes.AddPicture` to insert an image in an excel file.

I am calling the routine something like this :

```
leftPlacement=450;
topPlacement=20;
imgWidth=350;
imgHeight=300;

Shapes.AddPicture([pwd '\' img] ,0,1,leftPlacement,topPlacement,imgWidth,imgHeight);
```

This works fine. However, the image masks the data in the file. In order to change the position,  `leftPlacement, topPlacement, imgWidth imgHeight` have to be changed manually.

I am wondering, if there is a better way to do it to transparently place the image in the empty cells.

Comment: Do you know where the empty range is?  If yes, you can reposition the image by setting its TopLeftCell property.

Comment: Ya, I can find the range, Is it possible to put the image on the specific cell through Matlab. LIke if I would like to put the image in C9 and then mention size of the image

Comment: I'm not familiar with Matlab or how it interacts with Excel.  The code you posted looked like it might be using some of the built-in Excel properties: that's why I suggested the topleftcell approach.  Can you read properties from your excel file using Matlab?  Your range should have a Top and a Left property which you can use to position the image.

Comment: I can read/write properties from an excel file in Matlab. I am not aware of the method/function to use to place the image in the right cell.

Comment: Can you show a little more of your code - how do you get to the Shapes object ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shapes are not attached to individual cells in the Excel Worksheet - they float above them and have their own coordinates. If you want to float them above a particular cell, you can get the coordinates of that cell and use those.

So if you want to float it above cell C9, try

```
left = xl.ActiveSheet.Range('C9').Left;
top = xl.ActiveSheet.Range('C9').Top;
xl.ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture('myPicPath',0,1,left,top,myPicHeight,myPicWidth)
```

where xl is the variable containing your reference to the Excel application.

Note that if you subsequently resize, or otherwise move any of the cells, the position of the shape/image won't change - you'll need to reposition it again using the same method.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am not an expert in using excel macro. But this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Note that you probably switched between height and width.
See the reference here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shapes.addpicture